# How to combine two sql expressions into one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following issue:

> - It is necessary to write a query that will output **'item_id'**, **'price_in_byr'.**
> - **'price_in_byr'** is calculated as the **'price'** of the *items* table multiplied by the currency rate at the maximum date of the rate from the table *rates*.

[See Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNxkg.png)

I apologize for my English, I'll try to explain by example:

> Goods with item_id = 5 costs 20 euros, in the rates table the maximum date for the euro is January 12, at that date the exchange rate was 25.  Total our **'price_in_byr'** is 25 * 20 = 500

My solution with temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE tempRate SELECT currency, MAX(rate) AS maxRate FROM rates GROUP 
BY currency;

SELECT items.item_id,(ifnull(tempRate.maxRate,1) * items.price) AS price_in_byr
FROM items
LEFT JOIN tempRate ON items.currency = tempRate.currency;
```

***Tell me please, how can I do it in one query?***

Comment: MAX(rate) will return the highest rate regardless of its date, it will not produce the most recent rate (at the "maximum" **date**) - so that will not work regardless of how you do it, in one query or with a temp table.

Comment: It would help if you would pick the database product in the TABS section (bottom of your post). Tab-spamming (including MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle) doesn't help - Gordon edited your post to remove the "spam". If IFNULL works for you, that rules out Oracle, but otherwise we are left guessing.

Comment: @mathguy, Thank you for answers. I'm not strong in English and unfortunately it takes a long time to understand the answers. I'm trying to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    items.item_id,(ifnull(tempRate.maxRate,1) * items.price) AS price_in_byr
FROM 
    items
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT 
        currency, MAX(rate) AS maxRate 
    FROM 
        rates 
    GROUP BY 
        currency
    ) AS tempRate
    ON items.currency = tempRate.currency;
```

In practice, you substitute "tempRate" by `(definition of tempRate) AS tempRate`.

You can see an example at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=487e420047b811b5d8bde50816a6421c)*

---

If you actually want the * most_recent_rate*, you'd do something completely different; insert a subquery to compute it. This subquery looks for all rates of the given `currency`, sorts them by their `exchange_ts` (meaning timestamp) in descending order, and just picks to top 1:

```
SELECT 
    items.item_id,(ifnull(
    (
        SELECT 
            rate AS most_recent_rate
        FROM 
            rates
        WHERE
            rates.currency = items.currency
        ORDER BY
            exchange_ts DESC
        LIMIT 1    
    )
    , 1) * items.price) AS price_in_byr
FROM 
    items ;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=9ab07609b8e34a576cc39d02341727c4)*

Comment: MAX(rate) is not necessarily the rate at the "maximum **date**".

Comment: You're right, it's the maximum rate on the table for the given currency. Whether that's the intended value or not depends on the specific application. I'd *usually* look for the *exchange rate* of the *date (and time)* (or the previous available one) when the item was priced (or bought/sold). But whether this is the intended usage here or not, is up the original poster. The value is named with `maxRate`, not `currentRate` or `rateAtTimeOfSale`... So, interpretation is perfectly open.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `tempRate` query into a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    items.item_id,
    (ifnull(tempRate.maxRate,1) * items.price) AS price_in_byr
FROM 
    items
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT currency, MAX(rate) AS maxRate 
        FROM rates 
        GROUP BY currency
        ) as tempRate ON items.currency = tempRate.currency;
```

Comment: MAX(rate) is not necessarily the rate at the "maximum **date**".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if mysql supports this level of subquery but see if it works:

```
select I.item_id, I.price * CR.rt 
from 
items as I,
(
    select r.currency cy, r.rate rt
    from 
        rates as r, (select currency, max(date) max_date from rates group by currency) as R_MAXDATES
    where 
        r.currency = R_MAXDATES.currency 
        and r.date = R_MAXDATES.max_date;
) As CR
where
I.currency = CR.cy
```